# tc qdisc with GRE in openwrt

Tags: traffic-shaping, qos, tc, openwrt, gre

I'm trying to implement traffic control to GRE interface in an openwrt board. 
For this i followed below steps,

1. Create GRE interface named gre1 in both tunnel end devices.
2. Tested reachability with ping, Success.
3. create qdisc using following command.

   *`tc qdisc add dev gre1 root handle 1: default 2`*
4. Before creating tc classes i tired to ***ping the tunnel interface but this failed***. 
   5.I tried to capture packet in gre1 but found 0 packets.
5. Monitored the statistics of qdisc using the command

   *`tc -p -s -d qdisc show dev gre1`*

   found that ***packet drop count is increasing***.

I have tested this same in Ubuntu PC and found working. Also if i change the tunnel to VPN tunnel instead of GRE it working fine.

Is there any additional thing which I need to handle to implement tc in GRE ?

*Any help will be appreciated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed !

Add class

```
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 60kbps ceil 100kbps
```

then add sfq for the class

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: sfq
```